# new to sql/mysql cant figure out foriegn keys

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-design

```
CREATE DATABASE FINAL_PROJECT;

USE FINAL_PROJECT;

CREATE TABLE MOVIE_RATING
(RATING_ID VARCHAR (1) PRIMARY KEY,
RATING VARCHAR(4));

CREATE TABLE MOVIE
(MOVIE_ID VARCHAR (2) PRIMARY KEY,
TITLE VARCHAR(20),
YEAR_RELEASED VARCHAR(4),
RATING_ID VARCHAR(1),
BW VARCHAR(4),
SUBTITLES VARCHAR(5));

CREATE TABLE CAST
(CAST_ID VARCHAR (2) PRIMARY KEY,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(20),
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(4),
DOB VARCHAR(20),
DOD VARCHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE MOVIE_CAST
(MOVIE_ID VARCHAR (2), 
CAST_ID VARCHAR(2),
PERSONA VARCHAR(4));
```

I need to code a foreign keys for the tables here currently have no clue as to what to do for the following:

1. In the `movie` table I need to reference the `rating id` that is
   present in the `rating` table.
2. In the `cast` table i need to reference `movie` id and `cast` id
   from the `movie` table and `cast` table

Comment: Wow ! Profs are telling people to go to stack overflow to get the answers ? What about text books and teaching assistants ? Maybe you should pay the college fees to SO instead.

Comment: [Here's the FK Section for MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). The Prof has kindly kept the names of candidate foreign keys the same as the relevant primary keys in the original table, so it should be easy to spot them. Never store dates as varchar - use a relevant [Date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) type for this. `Year_Released` is also a candidate for an integer field.

Comment: Here is a quick tutorial. Not the best place to learn, but okay for now. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command will crate a foreign key:

```
alter table movie 
  add foreign key (rating_id)
  references rating(id);
```

---

I recommend renaming the `cast` table to something else, because `cast` is a built-in function. Maybe `movie_cast`.

Comment: when i use the alter table code i get an error that says SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE MOVIE
  ADD foreign key (rating_id)
  references  */                                                                                     CREATE TABLE MOVIE
(MOVIE_ID VARCHAR (2) PRIMARY KEY,
TITLE VARCHAR(20),
YEAR_RELEASED DATE,
RATING_ID VARCHAR(1),
BW VARCHAR(4),
SUBTITLES VARCHAR(5),
ALTER TABLE MOVIE
  ADD foreign key (rating_id)
  references rating(id);

Comment: @mic create the table. THEN run the alter command as a separate command. You seem to be trying to run the alter command as part of he create statement. You can define a FK as you define the table, but that uses a different syntax and your question already has the tables defined.

Comment: how would I write the query to define the fk

Comment: @mic the command should work. What you posted in your comment as the error message shows you have tried to mix the alter with the create. Just run the alter as a separate statement.